# Kafka consumer properties from the beginning in a topic

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, avro

I am trying to write a Kafka consumer to consume the messages from the beginning. I could do the same from console consumer using --from-beginning

But i couldn't find the respective properties in JAVA API.

```
 def consumeFromKafka(topic: String) = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest")
    props.put("group.id", "consumer-group")
    val consumer: KafkaConsumer[String, String] = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](props)
    consumer.subscribe(util.Arrays.asList(topic))
    while (true) {
      val record = consumer.poll(1000).asScala
      for (data <- record.iterator)
        println(data.value())
    }
  }
```

Also one more question on what should be the value.deserializer for Avro messages ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The impact `--from-beginning` that is used in the `kafka-console-consumer` can be achieved by setting `auto.offset.reset` to `earliest`. In combination with a unique/new `group.id` it has the same effect.

Basically, you want to create a new Consumer Group (through `group.id`) and as the Kafka Broker does not know this consumer group it automatically resets the offset for this consumer group based on the config `auto.offset.reset`. When set to `earliest` it will start from beginning. When set to `latest` it waits for new incoming data.

Regarding the Avro deserialisation this [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-streaming-consume-and-produce-kafka-messages-in-avro-format/) might help.

Comment: Avro deserialisation function from_avro is available only in Spark 2.4 and above , How to do deserialisation in scala instead of using spark.